# How to install mechanize for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

I saved mechanize in my Python 2.7 directory. But when I type `import mechanize` into the Python shell, I get an error message that reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import mechanize
ImportError: No module named mechanize
```

Answer (score 45):

using [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/):

```
pip install mechanize
```

or download the mechanize [distribution](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/src/) archive, open it, and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: and to get pip, use easy_install: easy_install pip

Comment: and to get easy_install use pip install easy_install or your package manager

Comment: and to get pip, use easy_install: easy_install pip or your package manager

Answer (score 19):

Try this on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mechanize
```

Comment: Assuming he's on Debian/Ubuntu. If he's on another distro then this won't work.

Comment: @justin and @ Estevan you both THANK YOU

Comment: thanks, I thought pip would do the job. In my case I installed with sudo apt-get install python3-mechanize

Comment: This is only working for python <3. I just upgrade to python3.5 and got this issue.

Answer (score 6):

You need to [follow the installation instructions](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/download.html) and not just download the files into your `Python27` directory.  It has to be installed in the `site-packages` directory properly, which the directions tell you how to do.

Comment: I looked through their site and didn't find a single mention of the site-packages thing. The readme says not to copy to site-packages the mechanize.x.x.x directory, but rather, the mechanize dir inside of it. that solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

I dont know why , but "pip install mechanize" didnt work for me . easy install worked anyway . Try this :

```
sudo easy_install mechanize
```

Comment: I beleive pip command is not available on mac.For easy_install worked

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did which worked:

```
yum install python-pip
pip install -U multi-mechanize
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo pip-2.7 install mechanize
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the actual package (the directory containing `__init__.py`) stored somewhere that's in your system's PYTHONPATH.  Normally, packages are distributed with a directory above the package directory, containing `setup.py` (which you should use to install the package), documentation, etc.  This directory is not a package.  Additionally, your `Python27` directory is probably not in PYTHONPATH; more likely one or more subdirectories of it are.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `python-setuptools` package:

`apt-get install python-setuptools` on Debian-ish systems
`yum install python-setuptools` on Redhat-ish systems

Use `sudo` if applicable

Answer (score 0):

install dependencies on Debian/Ubuntu:

`$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-matplotlib`

install multi-mechanize from `PyPI` using `Pip`:

`$ sudo pip install -U multi-mechanize`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to follow the installation instructions in Daniel DiPaolo's answer to try one of the two approaches below

1. install easy_install first by running "easy_install mechanize", or
2. download the zipped package mechanize-0.2.5.tar.gz/mechanize-0.2.5.zip and (IMPORTANT) unzip the package to the directory where your .py file resides (i.e. "the resulting top-level directory" per the instructions). Then install the package by running "python setup.py install".

Hopefully that will resolve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install mechanize
```

[mechanize](https://kite.com/python/docs/mechanize) supports only python 2.

For python3 refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774959/4773973 for alternatives.