# A script to automatically login to an account once a month

Tags: autologin

DynDNS requires a login to an account once a month to keep the free domains active. Is it possible to write simple script (in Linux) to do this? The login page is [this](http://account.dyn.com).

Comment: DynDNS provides applications that do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write it in python and host the script on a server such that it runs indefinetaly, you can use the Mechanize library to log in for you and the time built in to do it once a month.
Mechanize: http://stockrt.github.io/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/
Time: http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html
Free hosting: https://www.heroku.com/

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this:

```py
import re
import mechanize

username = "username"
password = "password"
success_verification_text = "Log Out"

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("https://account.dyn.com/")


#select the login form
for form1 in br.forms():
    form = form1
    break;

br.select_form(nr=0)

form["username"] = username
form["password"] = password

response = br.submit()


if success_verification_text in response.read():
    print "SUCCESS"
else:
    print "FAILED"
```

https://gist.github.com/mandarl/6007396

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login successfully you will need to select login form. 
Form ID changes between requests (loginNNN) so it's best to search for it by name.

Working example (requires [mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888463/how-to-install-mechanize-for-python-2-7)):

```
import re
import mechanize

username = "xxx"
password = "xxxxxx"
success_verification_text = "Log Out"

br = mechanize.Browser()

response = br.open("https://account.dyn.com/")

# select the login form
cnt = 0
for frm in br.forms():
    if str(frm.attrs["id"]).find("login") != -1:
        form = frm
        break
    cnt += 1

br.select_form(nr=cnt)

form["username"] = username
form["password"] = password

response = br.submit()

if success_verification_text in response.read():
    print ("SUCCESS")
else:
    print ("FAILED")
```